# PHP pdftk ASCII encoding issue

Tags: php, regex, string, character-encoding, preg-match-all

I wrote a function which passes a string containing PDF field data into preg_match_all() as the subject. However no matter what I do I cannot get the expected output as I'm getting here http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/bjN. On my development environment I'm getting this:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }

The only way I have been able to get this to work is by calling var_dump() on my string input, assigning this to a variable in my function and escaping the double quotes with back slashes. This solution won't work, however, because I would like to pass in different strings dynamically.

The functions I've already tried include preg_replace(), preg_quote(), addslashes(), addcslashes() and htmlentities() to escape or encode any characters which may be causing issues. Nothing has worked so far.

Quoted below is the output I get when calling var_dump() on my input. As I said above, assigning this to a variable and passing it into preg_match_all() works for me. So this issue seems to be boiling down to this: what could possibly be preventing my input string from working properly with preg_match_all() that isn't also an issue for the string I get when I call var_dump() on it?

> string(3277) "--- FieldType: Text FieldName:
>   fc-int01-generateAppearances FieldFlags: 5 FieldJustification: Left
>   --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Cake Size, Shape, and Pricing_edit;_aKGrUPU76IVzjjqnxACWRA FieldNameAlt: Please describe
>   custom cake sizing and special requests. FieldFlags: 0
>   FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Todays Date
>   FieldNameAlt: Today's date FieldFlags: 0 FieldJustification: Left ---
>   FieldType: Button FieldName: Type FieldFlags: 49152
>   FieldJustification: Left FieldStateOption: For delivery
>   FieldStateOption: For pick-up FieldStateOption: Off --- FieldType:
>   Text FieldName: Name FieldNameAlt: Name FieldFlags: 0
>   FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Date of Event
>   FieldNameAlt: Date of event FieldFlags: 0 FieldJustification: Left ---
>   FieldType: Text FieldName: Time of the event FieldNameAlt: Time of the
>   event FieldFlags: 0 FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text
>   FieldName: Type of event FieldNameAlt: Type of event FieldFlags: 0
>   FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Event location
>   (if delivery is requested) FieldNameAlt: Event location (if delivery
>   is requested) FieldFlags: 0 FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType:
>   Text FieldName: Pick Up Time FieldNameAlt: Pick up time FieldFlags: 0
>   FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Number of
>   Guests FieldNameAlt: Number of guests FieldFlags: 0
>   FieldJustification: Left --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Phone Number
>   FieldNameAlt: Phone number FieldFlags: 0 FieldJustification: Left ---
>   FieldType: Button FieldName: Cake Size, Shape, and Pricing FieldFlags:
>   49152 FieldJustification: Left FieldStateOption: Custom
>   FieldStateOption: Off FieldStateOption: Rectangle 1/2 Sheet ($60.00)
>   Serves up to 12 FieldStateOption: Rectangle 1/3 Sheet ($40.00) Serves
>   up to 8 FieldStateOption: Rectangle 1/4 Sheet ($30.00) Serves up to 6
>   FieldStateOption: Rectangle Full Sheet ($100.00) Serves up to 24
>   FieldStateOption: Round 6" ($40.00) Serves up to 8
>   FieldStateOption: Round 9" ($50.00) Serves up to 16
>   FieldStateOption: Square 1/6 Sheet ($20.00) Serves up to 4
>   FieldStateOption: Square 2/3 Sheet ($50.00) Serves up to 16 ---
>   FieldType: Button FieldName: Cake Flavors FieldFlags: 49152
>   FieldJustification: Left FieldStateOption: Carrot FieldStateOption:
>   Chocolate FieldStateOption: Lemon FieldStateOption: Off
>   FieldStateOption: Red velvet FieldStateOption: Vanilla --- FieldType:
>   Button FieldName: Cake Fillings FieldFlags: 49152 FieldJustification:
>   Left FieldStateOption: Buttercream FieldStateOption: Cream cheese
>   FieldStateOption: Dark chocolate FieldStateOption: Lemon curd
>   FieldStateOption: Off FieldStateOption: Strawberry mousse ---
>   FieldType: Button FieldName: Cake Frosting FieldFlags: 49152
>   FieldJustification: Left FieldStateOption: Chocolate buttercream
>   FieldStateOption: Cream cheese FieldStateOption: Off FieldStateOption:
>   Strawberry buttercream FieldStateOption: Vanilla buttercream
>   FieldStateOption: Whipped cream --- FieldType: Text FieldName: Cake
>   Inscription and Color of Writing FieldNameAlt: Cake Inscription and
>   Color of Writing FieldFlags: 4096 FieldJustification: Left ---
>   FieldType: Text FieldName: Toppings and Special Decorations
>   FieldNameAlt: Toppings and Special Decorations FieldFlags: 4096
>   FieldJustification: Left "

If I assign this string to a temporary variable and escape the quotes then preg_match_all() works as expected. When I call var_dump() on this variable with the assigned string then the length is 3268 characters vs. 3277 for my direct input (above). So maybe there is something weird going on with the input string.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Here is my class file which I have modified to enhance readability on here:

```
class Pdf_form {

    public function get_pdf_fields($pdf) {
        $cmd = "pdftk $pdf dump_data_fields output -";

        $descriptorspec = array(
           1 => array("pipe", "w")
        );

        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        if(!is_resource($process)) {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $dump_data = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);

        $status = proc_close($process);

        return $this->parse_fields($dump_data);
    }

    private function parse_fields($dump_data) {
        preg_match_all('/FieldType: .+?(?= ---|$)/', $dump_data, $field_data);

        return $field_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"which cannot be passed as input into preg_match_all because of the presence of $ and " (double quote) characters"_ Why would you think that?  This is obviously the subject and not the pattern and those characters won't present a problem.

Comment: You are right, the string I quoted is the subject. I didn't think there would be any problem myself until preg_match_all() returned this "array(1) { [0]=> array(0) { } }". Only after I escaped the $ and " with back slashes did preg_match_all() return what I expected. -- Edit: you are correct about the dollar signs not needing to be escaped, as I just tested this, but the double quotes are still proving problematic until they're escaped.

Comment: Can you post how you are running this string in `preg_match_all` or `preg_replace`?

Comment: replace `"` with `&quot;` html entitity

Comment: chris85: sure - I added it to my original post

Comment: Okay, code works perfectly fine as is (or at least on my 5.3.17 version). You sure you aren't modifying `$input` somehow? I had to escape the single quote in `Today's` so it could capture the whole sample input you gave in single quotes. `$input = '"--- FieldType:` etc. `Left "';`. Then `preg_match_all('/FieldType: .+?(?= ---|$)/', $input, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);`

Comment: chris85: I'm not modifying the input at all. What I quoted is what's being passed into preg_match_all(). If you're saying the solution is to escape the single quote, I already tried that using addslashes() and it doesn't help.

Comment: If the `$` in the pattern isn't an anchor you need to escape it.

Comment: Only should care about quoting source strings when they are parsed, not if they are already parsed. If you are just trying to fix up a string to write to a file, that's different.

Comment: Could you please post everything you have? As I've stated this works for me. @AbraCadaver isn't the `$` an anchor? It's looking for everything until the first occurrence of `---` or the end of the string.

Comment: This is all one big string with no linebreaks. And, the internal double quotes are being used as _inch_ ticks. The whole thing looks like output from some program. Whats the problem? Just grab the outter quotes, then quote the contents. `/"(.+)"/` then escape the inner quotes from capture group 1.

Comment: chris85: I just added the class file I'm using.

Comment: Replacing the double quotes should make no difference so get rid of `$dump_data = str_replace('"', '\"', $dump_data);`. The quoted output above was that from `var_dump($dump_data);` in this function? Also please use the `@` before the username to tag.

Comment: @sln: can you clarify what you mean by grab the outer quotes? The outer quotes aren't part of my input string, they're just being displayed because I called var_dump() on my input and pasted it here. I guess I should clarify that in my post.

Comment: @chris85: yes, the quoted output is from var_dump(). I just clarified that in my original post.

Comment: Then why are you using the var_dump() ? Wherever your string is just use the replace function on it. Oh, then use var_dump() to print the results... Even if you use replace on the dump string, you should still see all the quotes escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Newdoc syntax I think.

An example from the documentation.

```
echo <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

https://php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc11

**EDIT**
If you just want to replace all double qoutes you can use str_replace.

`$a = str_replace('"', '\"', $a);`

Comment: I don't see how this will work unless there's a way for me to somehow convert my dynamic input string into nowdoc format.

Comment: I missunderstood the question. But this should work to replace all double qoutes with \" `$string = str_replace('"', '\"', $string);`

Comment: The problem should be identified first before "fixes". There is no reason double quotes need to be escaped here.

Comment: Karl: I did the same thing using str_replace() as you suggest here but it was not successful in escaping the double quotes. I have no idea why this is happening other than the suspicion I mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out some, or maybe even all, of the characters which appeared to be spaces in my input were actually encoded as ASCII newline characters (ASCII decimal code 10). So somehow between calling pdftk's dump_data_fields operation and piping the data through stream_get_contents() to my php script the data became encoded in this way.

My solution is to call preg_replace() on my input to replace all of the newline characters with spaces. Here is what it looks like:

```
$dump_data = preg_replace('/\n/', ' ', $dump_data);

preg_match_all('/FieldType:.+?(?=.---|$)/', $dump_data, $field_data);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score -1):

Pass the string in the php function

```
mysqli_real_escape_string();
```

If you are using mysqli connect 
And if using mysql then use

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
```

Comment: What? No DB talk here.

Comment: You can use this function even if you don't want to save the record in DB. I mean it will return same thing whether you want to insert in DB or store in variable.

Comment: No first it will throw warnings. `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock)`, `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in`, etc. If the goal is just to escape quotes why not http://php.net/addslashes? But even that isn't the issue here.